# Gray rank algorithm implementation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, gray-code

How can I implement the following algorithm in python:

[image]
([source](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~ttomek/alk/GrayCodeRank.png))

```
def getGraycodeRank(n, t):
    r = 0#range
    b = 0
    for i in reversed(range(0, n)):
        if n - i IS IN t: #how to check it?
            b = 1-b
        if b == 1:
            r += 2^i
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`in`** operator:

```
if (n - i) in t:
```

or simply

```
if n - i in t:
```

Also, the operator `^` doesn't do what you think. To get the power of a number, use `**`:

```
r += 2**i
```

**Note:**

- The `in` operator will work with tuples, lists, dicts, strings.

**Edit:**

Since `t` is a string, to check if an integer (`n - i`) is contained by `t`, you will have to convert the integer `n - i` to a string:

```
if str(n - i) in `t`:
    # ...
```

Comment: assuming `t` is a `dict` or `list`.

Comment: when I tried to run:
print getGraycodeRank(4, "101")

I get:
if (n - i) in t: #how to check it?
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

Comment: @Fos What is the type of `n` and `t`?

Comment: @Fos you will have to convert the integer `4` to a *string*: `n = str(n)`

Comment: I dont get it. now I get error:
    for i in reversed(range(0, n)):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.

Comment: @Fos sorry for that. Try the new edit. Only use `str()` in the `if` so  you can use the operator `in`. You will need `n` to be an integer in the other operations.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `t` is a `dict` or `list`

```
if (n - i) in t:
```

this should work...